# I want format phone number column while selecting from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add +1 while trying to get data from a phone number column. example data(1234567890)

```
select phone_number from table1;

result
1234567880

desired result
+11234567880
```

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `concat()` or `||` operator

```
select concat('+1',phone_number) as phoneNumber from table1
```

OR

if data type of your phone_number column is number/int then you can use

```
select concat('+1',TO_CHAR(phone_number)) as phoneNumber from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original data has fixed length `10`, then you might consider using `lpad` with padded_length is `12` and pad_string is `+1`:

`select lpad(phone_number,12,'+1') from table1`